# "The system cannot find the path specified" when using mailto:

Tags: email, mailto

I'm trying to run mailto: from a batch file, and I'm getting the above error.  This is what the code looks like right now:

`mailto:"example@gmail.com?subject=Telework&body=I have started my workday.%%0D%%0A%%0D%%0AThank you,%%0D%%0AJohn Smith%%0D%%0A555-123-5678%%0D%%0A"`

The percent signs are escaped because otherwise batch interprets %0 as the 0th argument of the current command (ie the name of the batch file)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "run mailto" ?

Comment: i have the code above in a batch file, and i'm running the batch file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to url encode the whole thing, not just part of it (there are spaces at some places, and weird escaping in other places).

```
mailto:"example%40gmail.com%3Fsubject%3DTelework%26body%3DI%20have%20started%20my%20workday.%0A%0AThank%20you%2C%20%0AJohn%20Smith%0A%0A555-123-5678"
```

Online tools exist for URL encoding, e.g. https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: I copied this into my batch file, escaped the percent signs again, and still got an error (though a different one):

**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Comment: This kind of error is maybe not related to mailto at all. Try replacing the content of the file with `echo "lala"` and see if the same error appears. If it does, google the error (file path incorrect ? permissions problem ?).

Comment: It does not - it just outputs the text I echoed.